# Postgresql get user in certain radius

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I was trying to get all the users which in radius for the user who made request. I created a gps(geometry type) to store latitude and longitude.

I've used this code:

```
SELECT * From UserAddresses 
WHERE ST_DWithin(
   (Select gps 
    from useraddresses 
    where ID=(Select UserAddressID 
              FROM Users WHERE ID=1)), 
   (Select gps 
    from useraddresses 
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT UserAddressID 
                 FROM Users 
                 WHERE ID!=1)), 
    1609*(Select DiscoveryDistance 
          From Users 
          WHERE ID=1),true)
```

but it returns this error:

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

I know that this error comes from `SELECT UserAddressID FROM Users WHERE ID!=1` part but I couldn't fixed it.

All I want to do is compare `GPS` of `ID=1` to all user and if they're in the radius get their data.

Can anyone help me with the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You can move your condition outside of the subquery. `ST_DWithin` works on 1 row (for each geometry) at a time, so if you use a subquery it must also return just one row, and you probably have more than one `ID!=1` row.

```
SELECT targetAdr.* 
From UserAddresses srcAdr,
     UserAddresses targetAdr
WHERE srcAdr.ID=(Select UserAddressID 
                 FROM Users 
                 WHERE ID=1)
AND targetAdr.ID IN (SELECT UserAddressID 
                     FROM Users 
                     WHERE ID!=1)
AND ST_DWithin(srcAdr.gps, 
               targetAdr.gps, 
               1609*srcAdr.DiscoveryDistance,
               true);
```

Note that depending on how you assign the addressID, it might be much more efficient to simply do AND `targetAdr.ID != srcAdr.ID` instead of the possibly huge `IN` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have your "gps" columns as geometry type with metric SRID or if you use 4326 then you have geography type

```
SELECT *
  FROM UserAddresses ua1
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT FROM users u1, UserAddresses ua2, users u2 
                WHERE u2.id=1 
                  AND u1.id<>u2.id
                  AND u1.useraddressid=ua1.id
                  AND u2.useraddressid=ua2.id 
                  AND st_DWithin(ua2.gps, ua1.gps, u2.DiscoveryDistance*1609))
```

Remember to index gps column with GiST index.